# Independence between sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If I want to check that every element in the generated $\sigma-$algebra $\sigma(X)$ is independent from every element in the generated $\sigma-$algebra $\sigma(Y)$, is it enough to check the atoms are independent?

So, for example, if $A_1$ is an atom of $\sigma(X)$ and $A_2$ is an atom of $\sigma(Y)$, and if
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1)P(A_2),$$
does that mean every element in $\sigma(X)$ is independent from every element in $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: Are you sure you mean 'atom' and not 'element of $X$ or $Y$'? A $\sigma$-algebra may have no atoms.

Comment: What do you call an atom?

Comment: @Adayah In the problem I am given, there are atoms in both.

Comment: @nejimban An atom is a nonempty element of a $\sigma-$algebra that cannot be written as the union of any other elements in the $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 By this definition (more accurately by its likely intended meaning of an atom being an element of $\sigma$ that isn't union of two non-empty, non-identical elements of $\sigma$), most well-behaved non-discrete probabilities will have atoms of measure $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Borel sigma algebra on $[0,1/2]$ and the Borel sigma algebra on $[1/2,1]$  and the  probability measure $2m$ where $m$ is the Lebsgue measure.

The atoms of both sigma algebras are the singletons and they are independent but the sigma algebras are not.

Take $A_1=[0,1/2]$ and $A_2=[1/2,1]$